# animate clone of widget to another div on click

Tags: jquery

When I click on the `#Clonit` `div` I get a clone in `#result`. What CSS do I need to animate the apparent move from `#container` to `#result`?

Also, can anyone please tell me why the `removeAttr` function doesn't work?

The html:-

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="Clonit">Click me and I copy to another place</div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

The jquery:-

```
$("#Clonit").click(function() {
  $("#result").append($("#Clonit").clone(true));
  $("#result > #Clonit").removeAttr('id');
});
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cneeds/cnquesok/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have add this line in your code. Check it removeAttr is working like charm. What you need. be more specific.

```
$("#Clonit").click(function() {
    $("#result").append($("#Clonit").clone(true));
    $("#result > #Clonit").removeAttr('id');
    alert($("#result").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reverting to using `drag`. Check out some very useful resources at http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag#demos